# Versionable data format to work with Excel 2010

Tags: excel, csv, encoding, version-control

I need to work on tabular data with some people who will edit it using Excel 2010, likely set up with `,` as decimal delimiter and `;` as list separator.

The data needs to be under version control, and it must be easy to fork/share, merge, and compare different states of the data set. This includes low-barrier ways to contribute for people outside our work group who do not have me around to help them set the system up.

What setup will allow my co-workers to easily open the file using Excel and edit cells, and commit and compare with very few clicks and maybe entering a commit message?

In particular, I require that if I open the file in Excel, do a null-change and save it again, and then do whatever is the `commit` step for this setup, the commit will be empty.

The data contains non-ASCII characters, in particular IPA-symbols.

I expected that I would just be able to use `git` with `csv` files. But while for ASCII data, `.csv` with comma as separator seems to fulfill these conditions, for more complete encodings I cannot seem to get Excel keep data the same on round-trips, not even by appearance, not to mention binary compatibility – it either loses unicode characters upon saving or does not recognize the format upon reading.

Comment: I'm guessing that you haven't really gotten than many replies yet, because git is probably barely ever used for such purposes. If you want to put tabular data under version control (especially with Excel) then an SQL server (or any other DB server) comes to mind but not git. I guess you have your reasons. So, could you please elaborate why do you want to use some kind of CSV file and put these files under git version control? Don't you have any need to compare records, check for dupes, check for moving records, moving columns, etc.

Comment: Git is not actually a requirement, but I have expanded on the use case to clarify why I would like to use here. It should be fine if Excel played more nicely with unicode csv, like LibreOffice &c do.

Comment: Do you have a set of sample data you can add to the post?